# Dynamically loading tags and filtering them in model

Tags: laravel, cookies, eloquent

I am trying to get filter my model on certain tags that is in the relation of it. I currently have this code:

```
    $letters = \App\Letter::with(['tags' => function($query) {
        foreach(\Cookie::get('tags') as $tag => $name) {
            $query->where('tags.id', $tag);
        }
    }])->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->where('service','send')->where('mailbox_id', '=', Auth::user()->activeMailboxId)->paginate(8);
```

I want to get all Letters with the relationship Tags, so that I can then loop through the cookies and dynamically add where statements. But instead of only returning the Letters with the tags that is the cookie array, it returns all letters attached to my account, anybody an idea of how to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can use `WhereIn` which allow you to send array with the ids you need to get data from, Try this,

```
$letters = \App\Letter::with(['tags' => function($query) {

        //$tag array should be like this == [4,5,6]
        $query->whereIn('id', $tag);

    }])->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->where('service','send')
    ->where('mailbox_id', '=', Auth::user()
    ->activeMailboxId)
    ->paginate(8);
```

you can also try it like this

```
$letters = \App\Letter::with('tags')
        ->whereHas('tags',function($query) {

            //$tag array should be like this == [4,5,6]
            $query->whereIn('id', $tag);

        })->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->where('service','send')
        ->where('mailbox_id', '=', Auth::user()
        ->activeMailboxId)
        ->paginate(8);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It tells me ID is ambiguous but when i change 'id' to 'tags.id' it gives me back all letters attached to my account but it completely ignores the where in the 'subquery', what can i do?

Comment: have you got the `$tag` to `[1,2,4]` like array?

Comment: To debug it i even tried it like this: $query->whereIn('id', [48,49]); but it still says id is ambiguous. :(

Comment: It still gives back the same: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `letters` where exists (select * from `tags` inner join `letter_tag` on `tags`.`id` = `letter_tag`.`tag_id` where `letters`.`id` = `letter_tag`.`letter_id` and `id` in (48, 49)) and `service` = send and `mailbox_id` = 2354 and `letters`.`deleted_at` is null)

Comment: do you many to may relationship word can you get all tags to letter and letters to a tag?

Comment: It is a many to many relationship indeed, a letter can have many tags, but a tag can also be assigned to many letters

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172762/discussion-between-chamara-abeysekara-and-thimo-franken).